# search the selected options in a table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatable, datatables

I use dataTable class where it shows on top of the table the options for show, and search.

When I try to add ajax so that I can select new option from dropdown menu the search doesn't work.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="">
      <input type="text" id="row-1-age" name="row-1-age" value="John">
    </td>
    <td class="">
      <input type="text" id="row-1-age" name="row-1-age" value="Smith">
    </td>
    <td class="sorting_1">
     <input type="text" id="row-1-position" name="row-1-position" value="123">
    </td>
    <td>
     <select size="1" id="row-1-office" name="row-1-office">
       <option value="Active" selected="selected"> Active </option>
       <option value="Deactive"> Deactive </option>
       <option value="Delete"> Delete </option>                                      
     </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the code is like this the search tab is working fine but i can not change the option of the dropdown.
When i add 
at the  before the  the option can be selected but the search doesn't work.

Comment: add more code(javascript of datatable)

Comment: @pandian_Snkl I included <link href="bootstrap/vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
  <link href="bootstrap/vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: i asking for something related to Datatables like `var table = $("#example").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       { "type": "html-input", "targets": [1, 2, 3] }
    ] 
});`